# Ignore bootstrap validation on elements inside a hidden div

Tags: validation, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with 2 steps and with a continue button. At a time one step is visible. I have to validate only visible elements in each step. While using twitter bootstrap, when i go to next step the elements are getting highlighted as soon as the step is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching my own problem but I will try to help you.

I did steps with  [bootstrapWizard](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/). If step isnt validated not goes and focus on error. My problem is I cant validate wysihtml5 because its hidden and validation ignores it, and hidden:not didnt work on my steps..

That is my on next validation if validated goes to next step.

```
onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
var $valid = $("#form").valid();
if(!$valid) {
$validator.focusInvalid();
return false;
}
```

my validator,

```
var $validator = $("#form").validate({
});
```

Comment: BootstrapWizard looks good. But i am already using basic twitter bootstrap validation through out the site. Only this page with 2 steps seems to have an issue.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation , it looks fine and capable of doing everything except, hidden value bugs.